# Mudando o missing data <NA> por "outra coisa"

Tags: importação, r, spss

Quando eu importo um arquivo `.sav` eu não quero que apareça o carácter <NA> no meu `mydata1`. Gostaria que em vez de NA apareça, por exemplo, "Outra coisa".

```
mydata = read.spss('mydata.sav', use.value.labels = TRUE, to.data.frame = TRUE,
               max.value.labels = Inf, trim.factor.names = FALSE,
               trim_values = FALSE, reencode = "UTF-8")



(mydata1<- mydata[10:20,25:31])
   Q_16_O3 Q_16_O4 Q_16_O5 Q_16_O6 Q_16_O7 Q_16_O8 Q_16_O9
10    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
11    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
12    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
13    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
14    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
15    Trem    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
16    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
17    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
18    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
19    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
20    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

Colocando o `str` e o `dput`

```
str(mydata1)

'data.frame':   11 obs. of  7 variables:

 $ Q_16_O3: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA 4 NA NA NA NA ...

 $ Q_16_O4: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

 $ Q_16_O5: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

 $ Q_16_O6: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

 $ Q_16_O7: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

 $ Q_16_O8: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

 $ Q_16_O9: Factor w/ 10 levels "Ônibus","Vans",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...


dput(head(mydata1))


    structure(list(Q_16_O3 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L), .Label = c("Ônibus", 
    "Vans", "Metrô", "Trem", "BRT", "Barca", "Catamarã", "Fretados", 
    "VLT/Monotrilho", "Lotação (micro-ônibus especial)"), class = "factor"), 
    Q_16_O4 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("Ônibus", 
    "Vans", "Metrô", "Trem", "BRT", "Barca", "Catamarã", "Fretados", 
    "VLT/Monotrilho", "Lotação (micro-ônibus especial)"), class = "factor"), 
    Q_16_O5 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("Ônibus", 
    "Vans", "Metrô", "Trem", "BRT", "Barca", "Catamarã", "Fretados", 
    "VLT/Monotrilho", "Lotação (micro-ônibus especial)"), class = "factor"), 
    Q_16_O6 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("Ônibus", 
    "Vans", "Metrô", "Trem", "BRT", "Barca", "Catamarã", "Fretados", 
    "VLT/Monotrilho", "Lotação (micro-ônibus especial)"), class = "factor"), 
    Q_16_O7 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("Ônibus", 
    "Vans", "Metrô", "Trem", "BRT", "Barca", "Catamarã", "Fretados", 
    "VLT/Monotrilho", "Lotação (micro-ônibus especial)"), class = "factor"), 
    Q_16_O8 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("Ônibus", 
    "Vans", "Metrô", "Trem", "BRT", "Barca", "Catamarã", "Fretados", 
    "VLT/Monotrilho", "Lotação (micro-ônibus especial)"), class = "factor"), 
    Q_16_O9 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("Ônibus", 
    "Vans", "Metrô", "Trem", "BRT", "Barca", "Catamarã", "Fretados", 
    "VLT/Monotrilho", "Lotação (microônibusespecial)"),class="factor")),.Names=c("Q_16_O3", 
    "Q_16_O4", "Q_16_O5", "Q_16_O6", "Q_16_O7", "Q_16_O8", "Q_16_O9"
     ), row.names = 10:15, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Que tecnologia você está usando. Procure usar as tags para indicar melhor sobre o que está trabalhando.

Comment: Não conheço muito de r, mais pelo que parece se vc fizer `> mydata[is.na(mydata)] <- 0`, no caso substitui `<NA>` por `0`, veja se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562680/replacing-nas-with-0s-in-r-dataframe

Comment: Não funciona...

Comment: Na verdade, se fosse só NA em vez de <NA> funcionaria

Comment: Vasco, você poderia colocar o o resultado do `str(mydata)` na pergunta? (e se possível o resultado do `dput(head(mydata))` Ficaria mais fácil de entender o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Oi Carlos Cinelli. Veja se ficou bom... Obrigado

Comment: Cinelli, na verdade eu quero fazer um "freq" numa das filas dessas minha nova "mydata1"

Comment: Vasco, acho que entendi o seu problema, respondi ali, veja se atende, abs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O padrão do `read.spss` é transformar as variáveis categóricas em `factors` (categorias, fatores).

Quando uma variável é um `factor`, ela somente aceita aquilo que você definiu como os `levels` para ela. Então, quando você tenta fazer um `mydata[is.na(mydata)]<- "Outra coisa"` o `R` vai te dar a seguinte mensagem:

```
 Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "outra coisa") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Isto é, ele está te avisando que não existe o `level` "Outra coisa" e portanto está colocando `NA` no lugar.

A primeira coisa que você tem que ter em mente é o seguinte: por que você vai substituir um NA por uma outra categoria? Em geral, o NA quer dizer que a observação não existe, então talvez o mais apropriado seria deixá-lo como NA, pois o `R` sabe lidar com este tipo de coisa.

Por exemplo, se você quiser fazer uma tabela de frequência da primeira coluna do `mydata1`, você pode usar o comando `table` e ele irá omitir os NA (aqui estou usando os dados que você colocou no `dput(head(mydata1))` somente as 6 primeiras observações):

```
table(mydata1[,1])
                         Ônibus                            Vans                           Metrô 
                              0                               0                               0 
                           Trem                             BRT                           Barca 
                              1                               0                               0 
                       Catamarã                        Fretados                  VLT/Monotrilho 
                              0                               0                               0 
Lotação (micro-ônibus especial) 
                              0
```

Se você quiser que ele conte também os NA's, basta colocar o argumento `useNA="always"`:

```
 table(mydata1[,1], useNA="always")

                          Ônibus                            Vans                           Metrô                            Trem                             BRT 
                              0                               0                               0                               1                               0 
                          Barca                        Catamarã                        Fretados                  VLT/Monotrilho Lotação (micro-ônibus especial) 
                              0                               0                               0                               0                               0 
                           <NA> 
                              5
```

Repare que agora apareceu um campo <NA> com as 5 observações que são NA.

Mas, supondo que você queira realmente alterar o NA para outra coisa, então acho que a forma mais fácil seria a seguinte. Primeiro transforme os `factors` do seu `data.frame` em `characters` e depois substitua os NA por outra coisa.

Por exemplo, com o comando abaixo você seleciona todas as colunas de `mydata1` que são `factors` e as transforma em `character`:

```
mydata1[sapply(mydata1, is.factor)] <- lapply(mydata1[sapply(mydata1, is.factor)], as.character)
```

Agora você pode mandar um `mydata1[is.na(mydata1)] <- "Outra coisa"` que não vai gerar mensagem de erro.

Fazendo o `table` da primeira coluna, repare que agora temos 5 "Outra coisa" e 1 "Trem":

```
table(mydata1[,1])
Outra coisa        Trem 
          5           1
```

Comment: sensacional ...apanhei até encontrar essa resposta